# virtuemart component in joomla

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am new in joomla 1.5. I tried to implement virtuemart in my website. I download the the VirtueMart 2.0.8 (stable) from http://virtuemart.net/downloads.
During installing that, I got the following issue:
 "**Error! Could not find an XML setup file in the package.**".
How to solve this issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have doqwnloaded the 3.7MB package from the link you provided, you need to extract the file inside and upload and install each one manually.

Answer (score -1):

once you have download the VirtueMart 2.0.10 from http://virtuemart.net/downloads. you need to extract zip and install com_virtuemart.2.0.10.zip file